# Relation between refreshing the page and session expire

Tags: session-state

Is refreshing the page also means ending the session of one page and starting of new session of the same page if there is session_start() in the starting of the script?

Answer (score 1):

refreshing a web page will not expire or create a new session in server. session is a user(client) based variable will create and store when the user first request send to the web server.  so when you refresh a currently rendered page, only expiration time will reset. because the server created a session before you refresh the page and remember you by key (`sessionId`) put in your machine(in `cookie` mode) and till you have `aspnet session cookie` there is no reason for server to create a new session for you.  **so if you first time visit the page a new session will create for you and `session_start` will fire and when session expiration timeout exceeded(no request from user in a period of time) or the session abandonned(forced out), `session_end` will fire(assuming we are in `InProc` mode) and refreshing the page causes reseting expiration time and session is more alive.**