# Logging out after session time expires

Tags: java, session

In my web application (primefaces/java) I have 30min session time (implemented in js), after session ends I have dialog 'your session expired' and after clicking on 'ok' button we are redirected to /logout page and user is logged out properly.
But if I have 'your session expired' dialog, and I refresh page instead of clicking 'ok' button - we are not logged out - session is resetting, and we have 30 min session time again.

I tried to delete JSESSIONID cookie after dialog, but I do not have access to this cookie via js :/

Also I tried to triggen invalidateSession function on dialog open event, but it now works for me

```
<p:ajax event="open" listener="#{footerBean.invalidateSession()}"/>

_________

public void invalidateSession() {
    session.invalidate();
}
```

Do You know how to clear session cookie or something else to avoid refreshing session on page refresh after dialog 'session expired' shows?
Solution could be in jsf or js side

Comment: easiest way to expire session is to redirect the page to logout without dialog, or if you have to show the dialog then make an ajax call behind to expire the session. otherwise refreshing page is a legitame way to extend the session. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27388926/175554

Comment: yes, i know, but this dialog is must have for me. Now my solution is sending GET logout request by jquery

Comment: Sending the GET logout request via ajax seems easy - just send it as part of the code that shows the dialog, and before showing it. What are the downsides?